# Redux store updating but no rerender

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

Hi first post here so please go easy with me. I new to redux and wondered why im not get a rerender when my store is being updated successfully.

here is my reducer

```
const initialState = {
    pending: false,
    loadPlanning: [],
    error: null
}

export const loadPlanningReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    if (action.type === INITIALISE_LOAD_PLANNING_PENDING) {
        return {
            ...state,
            pending: true
        }
    }
    if (action.type === INITIALISE_LOAD_PLANNING_SUCCESS) {
        console.log('updating state');
        return Object.assign({}, state, {
            ...state,
            pending: false,
            loadPlanning: state.loadPlanning.concat(action.loadPlanning.items)
        });
    }
    if (action.type === INITIALISE_LOAD_PLANNING_ERROR) {
        return {
            ...state,
            pending: false,
            error: action.error
        }
    }
    return state;
}
export default loadPlanningReducer;

export const getLoadPlanning = (state) => { console.log('reducer state',state); return state.loadPlanning };
export const getLoadPlanningPending = (state) => state.pending;
export const getLoadPlanningError = (state) => state.error;
```

The view looks like

```
const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => ({
    error: getLoadPlanningError(state),
    loadPlanning: getLoadPlanning(state),
    pending: getLoadPlanningPending(state),
    options: state.options.options,
    option: state.options.currentOption,
    oidc: state.oidc
})

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        dispatch
    };
}

const fetchLoadPlanning = async (props) => {
    props.dispatch(initialiseLoadPlanning());
    const httpOptions = {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Authorization': `Bearer ${xxxxxxxx}`
        }
    };
    fetch('/Api/Planning/Get_Data?' + "database=xxxxxx", httpOptions)
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(res => {
            if (res.hasError) {
                throw res.error;
            }
            props.dispatch(initialiseLoadPlanningSuccess(res.data));
            return res.data;
        })
        .catch(error => {
            props.dispatch(initialiseLoadPlanningError(error));
        });
}

const LoadPlanningList = (props) => {
    useEffect(() => {       
        fetchLoadPlanning(props);
    }, [])

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log('props changed',props);
    },[props])
}
```

The console log of props changed happens on change of props.pending but not on the dispatch of props.dispatch(initialiseLoadPlanningSuccess(res.data));

[console log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6i8hK.png)

You help and wisdom would be most helpful, thanks in advance

Comment: where the code for your component ?

Comment: So the issue wasnt actually in the reducer it was the way i was accessing the page. Issue now resolved

Comment: you can mark this as resolved.